# What can i tell as a reason to the interviewer about being unemployed

Tags: interviewing, resume, work-experience

Most freshers/recent graduates and job seekers face a question of why were you idle for so many days after completing the studies. What answer can he give as a reply? Here are a few cases:

1. Done a certification course
2. Got placed and seeking for better opportunity
3. Went through course and yet to take up certification
4. In a job, but applied as fresher because of acceptance bond in other company
5. got offer and rejected for bad CTC

How best does one answer this question in a job interview?

Comment: I attempted to fix the formatting and add some detail to the question.

Comment: Is this a hyptothecial question or an actual issue you are facing? In that last case: why were you idle?

Comment: How about the truth? I'm sure most companies know the current financial situation makes it really hard to find a job. Especially your first job after graduating.

Comment: What do you mean by "many days"?

Comment: many days-more than 6 months, now a days companies come for on-campus recruitment i.e.,the process starts by 1month of final year,so its literally I didnt get a job for a year and 5 months(a practical scenario my friend is facing )

Comment: First , i would take opportunity thank you all for your valuable comments and answers to help job seekers.. Nice community .. Thanks all

Comment: What is CTC...?

Comment: Cost to company (annual package like 3000usd/annum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell the truth - Employers aren't usually worried about a few weeks of unemployment/inactivity after graduation. They recognize that the last year of the course can be pretty intense and you may want a while to yourself to relax, unwind and focus on where you go next. Chances are you didn't have a break for 6 months or so, you've earned a rest!

If it starts to stretch beyond a month, I'd be looking to see what the person was doing - were they applying for jobs? Were they busy moving home? I'd only be concerned if my job had been advertised for two months and they hadn't bothered applying while idle - if they're so keen to work for me, surely they've been keeping tabs on my company?

If you've been travelling, tell them that - it shows you've got a bit more to you than textbooks. If you'd been working part time while studying and wanted to spend some time in the countryside after several years of your degree, tell them that too.

And finally, stop worrying about it - chances are they understand. Even if you just weren't sure about what you wanted to do next and took a while to think about it, that's probably fine too - I'd rather have someone apply *after* deciding what they want to do for their career, rather than *before*

Answer (score 4):

The answer is always to tell the truth. Of you say you were doing a course and I find out that you weren't, you're going to be out of a job *really* quickly.

Comment: If we do course on GRE and we seek for a job to get financial support (say for 2 years only) , the company H R feels that the candidate may quit soon and investing on him becomes waste

Comment: That doesn't seem to have much to do with your question.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking us which lie to tell. This is not ideal. And the examples you mention are ridiculous. Why would you claim to have taken a course, when there's a good chance it's going to be checked out by your potential employer?

Tell the truth. If you were idle because you simply needed some time to yourself, say so.

Answer (score 1):

I handed in my thesis on Feb 28th. These are my "excuses" why I didn't send out all my applications on March 1st:

- First, I took some days off as a way to relieve from the stress of the last weeks finishing my thesis; and catching up some sleep.
- Then, finding work starts with searching and asking and preparation - finding my strengths, writing my resume, and esp. finding companies to send it to.
- I had personal reasons to go slow: I visited my grandmother fairly often because she had stumbled on the stairs and needed some help around the house while recovering. I took the time since I could.
- I was waiting for my certificate (the day after I I got my certificate, I sent out the first applications)
- After that, I was never completely idle - but I can't send the applications before I have found suitable open positions.

The most important thing is: this is the truth, although I must admit that I had a good time searching for open positions. If I had wanted, I could have sped up the process. ;)